# issue in getting device ip address from a javascript webpage

Tags: javascript, json, ip-address

I have this `JavaScript` code in my webpage:

```
const configDefault = {

  Bot: {
    // initial sessionAttributes
    sessionAttributes: {},

  },

};
```

Now What I want is to set the `sessionAttributes` with the `ip address` of the device on which this webpage is opened by the user. Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only)   I wrote this code to get the `ip address` of the device but I am having issue in first extracting the `ip address` out of the returned `json` object and then integrating this piece so that `sessionAttributes` in my code above is set with the `ip address`:

```
function myIP() {
    $.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
  JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
}
```

The `json` object in above code return following sample structure. I want to get `ip` field out of it and set it to `sessionAttributes` in my code at the top:

```
{
  "ip": "116.12.250.1",
  "country_code": "SG",
  "country_name": "Singapore",
  "region_code": "01",
  "region_name": "Central Singapore Community Development Council",
  "city": "Singapore",
  "zip_code": "",
  "time_zone": "Asia/Singapore",
  "latitude": 1.2931,
  "longitude": 103.8558,
  "metro_code": 0
}
```

I am new to JavaScript so I am unable to find a way to do this. Can anyone help me in structuring this right way?

**Update: My current code is at  http://js.do/code/158408 . I am getting error on `$` sign when I run it**

```
const configDefault = {

      Bot: {
        // initial sessionAttributes
        sessionAttributes: {},

      },

    };

function myIP() {
        $.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    });
    }

const ipInformation = myIP();
configDefault.Bot.sessionAttributes.ip = ipipInformation.ip;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use JSON.parse instead of stringify.

```
const ipInformation = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(ipInformation.ip);

const configDefault = {
  Bot: {
    // initial sessionAttributes
    sessionAttributes: {},
  },
};

configDefault.Bot.sessionAttributes.ip = ipipInformation.ip;

console.log(configDefault);
```

or if you wanted all of ipInformation in sessionAttributes.

```
configDefault.Bot.sessionAttributes = ipipInformation;
```

As $.getJSON is async, you'll need to do all the work inside the callback:

```
let configDefault = {
  Bot: {
    // initial sessionAttributes
    sessionAttributes: {}
  }
};

function myIP(configDefault) {
  $.getJSON("//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
    const ipInformation = JSON.parse(data);
    configDefault.Bot.sessionAttributes.ip = ipInformation.ip;
    console.log(configDefault);
    return configDefault;
  });
}

configDefault = myIP(configDefault );
```

Comment: how do I use this to set the `sessionAttributes` in my code above?

Comment: So `const ipInformation = JSON.parse(data);` will call the `myIP()` function in my post?

Comment: No. You need to replace JSON.stringify in your myIP function with `return JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: I have posted an updated version in my post above in update section based on your answer. Does the structure looks correct?

Comment: It looks correct, does it work? Make sure to open the console with F12 in case there are any errors.

Comment: Are you including jQuery?

Comment: You need to be bringing in jquery somewhere: `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I added above line in my code on the link in my last comment. Still same error. Is it possible you can check the code link and edit on it?

Comment: I can't run it from there to test because the call is blocked but something like: http://js.do/code/15842134a

Comment: the code in above link is also throwing `invalid character at line 20`. I am also getting same error on my version of code

Comment: does `console.log()` prints it? How can I print the ip address coming on these online editors to see if ip address is coming or not

Comment: When I run it I do not see any ip address printing on screen.